# Difference between Properties dictionary and Variables dictionary in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

With NLog I can add a property with:

```
eventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
eventInfo.Properties.Add(name, value);
```

and a variable with:

```
loggerInstance = LogManager.GetLogger(typeName);
loggerInstance?.Factory.Configuration.Variables.Add(name, value);
```

and then I ask myself: what is the difference? Have looked around but have not found a clear explanation just warnings that gdc, mdc, and mdlc are obsolete. Which one these should I use for what purpose - I may need both (or neither.)

Comment: You should avoid modifying the global NLog Variables at runtime. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer for details about the different context propeties.

Comment: To be more transparent, if I want a variable associated with only a particular logger instance then how do I do that? Alternatively, if I want a variable associated with all logger instances in the application then how do I do that? I can associate and instance of LogEventInfo with a particular logger thru my wrapper (which I have for other reasons) and can query that object by keyword to get the matching value for that logger instance. This appears to be what I want for a local store but is it within the intended purpose of that object and will it cause problems to use it that way?

Comment: Global properties for all loggers can be configured using GDC: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer . Sadly enough one cannot configure a property for single Logger. See also discussion https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference

- `eventInfo.Properties`: the context on the scope of one logEvent. You can render them with `${event-properties:myPropName}`
- `Configuration.Variables`: variables used in your nlog.config with `<variable /`>. You can use them in the config as:

  - `${var:myVar}`- dynamic, but only for properties with the `Layout` type
  - `${myVar}` - for all properties, will be applied when parsing the nlog.config

> gdc, mdc, and mdlc are obsolete

The classes GDC, MDC and MDLC are obsolete, but **not** `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` `MappedDiagnosticsContext` and `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`.

Those are the threadsafe contexts for:

- `GlobalDiagnosticsContext`: full application. Render with `${gdc:myKey}`
- `MappedDiagnosticsContext`: current thread, but threads created by this thread. Render with `${mdc:myKey}`
- `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`: current thread including threads created by this thread. Render with `${mdlc:myKey}`.

For more info, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=context

Comment: GlobalDiagnosticsContext is the application-wide store but at this moment there is no logger instance store. Was hoping to find a solution to that problem which could be wrapped (because wrap is required anyway) and also use the feature in an unwrapped way.

Comment: You could do GDC + Loggername as prefix ;)

Comment: Since NLOG 5.0, you have to use [ScopeProperty](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer) (with <logger>.PushProperty) instead of mdc/mdlc (with MappedDiagnosticsContext/MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext).